# iterating over hierarchical data to create a flattened table view in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iteration, html-table

I'm trying to create valid tabular markup using AngularJS but cannot figure out how to do it.  I have seen similar questions, but none that specifically meet my needs.

I have some race result data stored in a structure as follows:

```
{
    "date": "1900-01-01",
    "venue": "Venue",
    "results": {
        "10k": {
            "freestyle": {
                "male": [
                    "...a bunch of individual racer results"
                ],
                "female": [
                    "...a bunch of individual racer results"
                ]
            },
            "classical": {
                "male": [
                    "...a bunch of individual racer results"
                ],
                "female": [
                    "...a bunch of individual racer results"
                ]
            }
        },
        "5k": {
            "freestyle": {
                "male": [
                    "...a bunch of individual racer results"
                ],
                "female": [
                    "...a bunch of individual racer results"
                ]
            },
            "classical": {
                "male": [
                    "...a bunch of individual racer results"
                ],
                "female": [
                    "...a bunch of individual racer results"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So it's structured as: distance, style, gender, individual racer.

I can render these results into individual tables as follows:

```
<div ng-show="race.results" ng-cloak>
        <div ng-repeat="(dist, styles) in race.results">
                <div ng-repeat="(style, genders) in styles">
                        <div ng-repeat="(gender, finishers) in genders">
                                <table class="raceResultsTable">
                                        <tr>
                                                <th class="raceEvent" colspan="6">
                                                        <h3 class="tableHeading" id="{{ dist|createKey }}_{{ style|createKey }}_{{ gender|createKey }}_results">{{ dist }} {{ style }} {{ gender }}</h3> <a href="#result_index" class="backToTop" title="Back to results index">&#65514;</a>
                                                </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                                <th><strong>Place</strong></th>
                                                <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
                                                <th><strong>Age</strong></th>
                                                <th><strong>Age Group</strong></th>
                                                <th><strong>Time</strong></th>
                                                <th><strong>Pace</strong></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="racer in finishers | orderObjectBy:'place'">
                                                <td>#{{ racer.place }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ racer.name }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ racer.age }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ racer.age_group }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ racer.time }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ racer.pace }}/k</td>
                                        </tr>
                                </table>
                                <p></p>
                        </div><!-- genders -->
                </div><!-- styles -->
        </div><!-- distances -->
</div><!-- show/hide -->
```

This creates a lot of extra markup just to facilitate the iteration, but it works.  The problem I have is that I want an index at the top.  Originally it was just one line anchors to the H3's ID in each table.  That worked fine.  However, now I want to include export links along with the link to the on-page table and to get everything aligned I want to drop it into a table, but I'm not sure how to do this.  To have each row in the same table requires having multiple `ng-repeat` iterators on what are essentially "dummy" elements, but I don't know that I can do that and generate valid markup inside of a `<table>`.

Ideally, I'd be able to do something like...

```
<tr ng-repeat="(dist, (style, (gender, finishers) in genders) in styles) in race.results">
  <td><a href="#{{dist}}_{{style}}_{{gender}}_results">{{dist}} {{style}} {{gender}}</a></tr>
  <td><a href="#" class="download">CSV</a></td>
</tr>
```

AngularJS requiring that all of its logic be attached to DOM elements means it requires generating unnecessary markup.  I saw one reference to creating a "directive", which looked pretty foreign to me.  I'm not opposed to learning the ins and outs of AngularJS, but this strikes me as something that ought to be straightforward.  In a templating system like Twig this would be a snap, but I feel like I'm going to have to jump through a lot of hoops to accomplish this with AngularJS.

Is there a straightforward way to do this that doesn't involve all of the logic being inside of my controller?  If the directive approach is the only option, so be it, but I would consider this a huge mark against AngularJS and my interest in pursuing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem here is that ng-repeat only works on arrays of data. You want it to iterate over objects of data, which isn't going to work.  You need to change your data structure, or hardcode your template for each level of hierarchy.

Comment: Well, it does work (the part that generates the results tables in the second code listing in my Q), and the Angular docs do describe the "(key, value) in data" for iterating over object properties, so that's not an issue.  You're most likely right though that restructuring the data is what I'll need to do.  I was really hoping for enough flexibility in Angular to work with what I have and not need to massage/restructure it, but I guess it is what it is.

Comment: I guess you're right. I could have sworn I read something where it said this wouldn't work, so I ended up reformatting a bunch of stuff to make it work. I've started a Plunker on this to see if I can get it working. http://plnkr.co/edit/jEr64nmDhDXJ74S5iMjU

Comment: Other than the sorting, I have it working in the above plunker.